# Run a code after 10s if a variable didn't change

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a game for a discord bot that use the Discord.js API and I try to run a code after 10s if the variable playing (true/false) didn't change (to avoid a first person finish his game and a second person launch a new game and get time's up after a few seconds), so I already done the 10s timer but I can't resolve the second problem, so this is a simplified version of my code:

```
if(message.content === "?guess"){
playing = true;
  setTimeout(function(){
    message.reply("time's up!");
    playing = false;
  }, 10000);
}
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Unclear question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an if condition inside the setTimeout callback to check if they're still playing and only then end the game.

```
const globalGameTimeout = null;

...
if(message.content === "?guess"){
  playing = true;

  globalGameTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    if (playing) {
      message.reply("time's up!");
      playing = false;
    }
  }, 10000);
}

....
if (user guessed correctly or game ends in some other way) {
  clearTimeout(globalGameTimeout);
}
```

The clearTimeout(..) will make sure that an old setTimeout doesn't still execute falsely when another player has ended the preivous game and started a new one.

Comment: Yes but if i win the game (the playing variable go to false) and someone launch a game (the playing variable go to true) after that he will get the "time's up" message in less than 10s

Comment: You want to clear the old timeout then if the current game has ended. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Updated the answer with clearTimeout

Comment: ok I change the const to let because I was getting an error and now it's work thank!